# Monte Carlo probability approximation vs Histogram

Tags: monte-carlo, particle-filter, sequential-monte-carlo

I am trying to learn the sequential Monte Carlo method (particle filter) in data assimilation. In this method, the aim is to approximate the CDF of the target variable having a random sample of the sampling distribution. My question is what is the difference between MC approximation and Histogram. More specifically, why can't we use the histogram approach of approximating the PDF and then CDF?

Comment: To create an histogram you need data. When running SMC the goal is to produce data. Hence the goals are somewhat opposite.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Xi'an. About the Monte Carlo approximation of probability, we do need a sample to approximate the CDF from it, right? So in this sense both methods need a sample. I was wondering maybe it is not straightforward to obtain CDF from the estimated PDF in the histogram approach. But the thing, that is my question, so I am not sure at all.